# Java, Illegal Access Error when accessing another class

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I am trying to write a ssl decryption program. I found some old code from 2010 and have tried to get it to run. After finally being able to compile it I now get this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite from class sun.security.ssl.decrypt at sun.security.ssl.decrypt.main(decrypt.java:36)`

which is the line where I call CipherSuite.valueOf(0x00, 0x2f); (deleted some comment lines that's why it might be another line number here)
Now I have read that it would probably be a problem with the method valueOf() being private. Since I am a newbie to java I don't know how to handle that, because the code I would need to change is in a jar. (Using openjdk-1.7)
On the other hand, it says [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/ssl/CipherSuite.java#CipherSuite.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29)
that the method is just static. Also checking with .isAvailable() like recommended in the link above (at the .valueOf method) does not help.
Any suggestions?
Here is the code I got so far:

```
package sun.security.ssl;

import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.security.internal.spec.TlsKeyMaterialParameterSpec;
import sun.security.internal.spec.TlsKeyMaterialSpec;
import sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.BulkCipher;


public class decrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        byte[] clrnd = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("be9b706c800f93526913732a356c7e7fe9383ace52f5ed120d38a81db07e903d");
        byte[] srvrnd = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("56af786428bc3e0c69ef2fdd9f6e3456ceae660a323d6109e9554b4af7fe6652");
        ProtocolVersion pv = ProtocolVersion.valueOf(0x03, 0x03);
        CipherSuite cipher_suite = CipherSuite.valueOf(0x00, 0x2f);
        String KeyAlgo = cipher_suite.cipher.algorithm;
        String Master_Key = "c55ca8dd56fa59b80b8ff01d9a1d4f04251aec41ab6340e8db118b3d4d2ef895cc51592f9bcd5dbde5eda9d5ad386f34";
        byte[] master_secret = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(Master_Key);
        byte[] client_app_data = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("715e388b6ed9339faa6fc640f329c358");

        SecretKey masterkey = new SecretKeySpec(master_secret, 0, master_secret.length, KeyAlgo);

        //Calculate connection keys
        BulkCipher cipher = cipher_suite.cipher;
        int expandedKeySize = cipher_suite.exportable ? cipher.expandedKeySize : 0;

        KeyGenerator kg = JsseJce.getKeyGenerator("SunTlsKeyMaterial");
        int pv_major = pv.major;
        int pv_minor = pv.minor;
        try {
        kg.init(new TlsKeyMaterialParameterSpec(masterkey, pv_major, pv_minor, clrnd, srvrnd, cipher.algorithm, cipher.keySize, expandedKeySize, cipher.ivSize, cipher_suite.macAlg.size, cipher_suite.prfAlg.getPRFHashAlg(), cipher_suite.    prfAlg.getPRFHashLength(), cipher_suite.prfAlg.getPRFBlockSize()));
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(decrypt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        TlsKeyMaterialSpec keySpec = (TlsKeyMaterialSpec)kg.generateKey();

        SecretKey clntWriteKey = keySpec.getClientCipherKey();
        IvParameterSpec clntWriteIV = keySpec.getClientIv();

        SecureRandom clientrandom = new SecureRandom(clrnd);

        CipherBox svbox = cipher_suite.cipher.newCipher(pv, clntWriteKey, clntWriteIV, clientrandom, false);
        try {
            svbox.decrypt(client_app_data, 5, client_app_data.length-5, 0);
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(decrypt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println(svbox);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without being an expert in this area; and not having the time to start searching the net myself: I think in general, you do not want to use packages that have "sun" in their name - even when they exist in some version of Java, there are no guarantees that the next version will have them; or that they work the same way as before. In that sense: better forget about this example. Search the net for alternatives that are based on "official" componentry to do what you need (there should be plenty of real open-source alternatives).

Comment: well I've been looking for some solution for a few months now. and this is the closest i have gotten to solve this problem. i was looking at jsse but i cannot find out how to use sockets with a already captured connection. i have a pcap file and the masterkey and i would somehow need to make an offline socket connection feeding it the packets, but it seems not possible. so my only way is to use something to put in the data i have and decrypt my data directly. i hope its understandable what i mean. but thanks for the input @Jägermeister - Danke ;)

Answer (score 1):

I **guess** because it uses the default access modifier.

[Java Access Modifiers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXrFk.png)

The class sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite uses the default access modifier. This means that you can only access this class from the same package, which is not the case in your project.

[CipherSuite class definition](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/ssl/CipherSuite.java)

Comment: isn't it enough to write package sun.security.ssl at the top of the program? thats what it says in the CipherSuite class definition you linked.

Comment: overlooked that, sorry :)